# Error 500 when trying to access Dropbox API via Dropbox SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox-api

I have an app that via Dropbox Javascript SDK trying to download the file. I don't have any idea what is wrong. Accessing Dropbox API via fetch calls directly bringing the same error.

```
const Dropbox = require("dropbox").Dropbox;
import axios from "axios";
import { logger } from "./logger";

export class FileHandler {
    public async handle(path: string, token: string): Promise<void> {
        try {
            const dbx = new Dropbox({ fetch: axios, accessToken: token });
            dbx.filesDownload({ path })
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    logger.error(error);
                });

        } catch (err) {
            logger.error(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Error is the follow:

```
Request failed with status code 500 {"stack":"Error: Request failed with status code 500\n    at createError (/Users/andreyshedko/Repositories/agroproject-ftp/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/Users/andreyshedko/Repositories/agroproject-ftp/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/andreyshedko/Repositories/agroproject-ftp/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:237:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)\n    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)","config":{"url":"https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download","method":"post","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Authorization":"Bearer ...","Dropbox-API-Arg":"{\"path\":\"/1/price.xlsx\"}","User-Agent":"axios/0.19.0"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1}}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation, it says some things about authorization and cors

Comment: Http error 500 is 'Internal server error'. Victor F is right this is a problem with authentication or the way you connect to the server. https://www.ionos.com/community/server-cloud-infrastructure/apache/how-to-fix-http-error-code-500-internal-server-error/

Comment: @VictorF, please add your comments as the answer.

Comment: @andrey.shedko I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect/authorize in the correct way, see [the documentation](https://dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation).